# Mutiple AND condition In Select query PHP myadmin MYSQL one condition Not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $_SESSION['post'] = array($_SESSION['gender'],$_SESSION['star'],$_SESSION['caste'],$_SESSION['marital'],$_SESSION['salary'],$_SESSION['education'],$_SESSION['from'],$_SESSION['to'],$_SESSION['district'],$_SESSION['country_liv']);
    $post=$_SESSION['post'];
 echo $post[9]; //printing the country value
$page = (int)(!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
if ($page <= 0) $page = 1;


$per_page = 5; // Set how many records do you want to display per page.
$startpoint = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;

$statement = "`tbl_member` where member_id!=$member_id  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())>='$post[6]' AND 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())<='$post[7]' AND gender Like '$post[0]%' AND star LIKE '%$post[1]%' AND caste LIKE '%$post[2]%' AND  mari_status LIKE '%$post[3]%' AND education LIKE '%$post[5]%' AND city_town LIKE '$post[8]%' AND month_income LIKE '%$post[4]%' AND country_liv LIKE '%$post[9]%'"; 


  $results=mysqli_set_charset($conDB, "utf8");
$results = mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");
```

Now I'm Edited...
Its my over all coding please help me....

I want to show specific country in the results....

I can get the user input but when i use this query its not working..
Now I'm Edited...
Its my over all coding please help me....

I want to show specific country in the results....

I can get the user input but when i use this query its not working..

Comment: what is your ```country_liv```? Is it a ```varchar``` or ```int``` in your database?

Comment: plz chk if ur staement is generated correctly , i mean your print your select query and check if all values are printed in it.

Comment: country_liv is varchar

Comment: @Purushottamzende  $results = mysqli_query($conDB,"SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}");
select query

Comment: What is the output of `echo $post[9];`?

Comment: country Name like India Autralia

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate all session variables again into another session variable $_SESSION['post'] = array($_SESSION['gender']......? Why don't you just $post = array($_SESSION['gender']........  Can you please do an "echo $statement;" to see what its generating?

Comment: @rameshkanna, i meant in diffrent way. plz try this above ur results line and check what is printed echo "SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$per_page}"; or remove braces if u get any error.

Comment: Storing All variables in a array and using those variable in pagination if variables not stored in session It will so error when click next page

Comment: @Purushottamzende  If remove braces I'm not getting any error but it wil returns nothing from the database

Comment: Now I'm Edited... Its my over all coding please help me....

I want to show specific country in the results....

I can get the user input but when i use this query its not working..

Comment: @rameshkanna, go to table and put your all values statically there and check if record is returned, if record is shown then there is soemthing wrong in how u pass the query from code to DB and if it does not return record then u dont have matching values.

Comment: @Purushottamzende If i change the condition AND into OR it works but not show specific record like particular gender district...

Comment: @rameshkanna, then definitely ur conditions are wrong. or record is not present satisfying all those values.

Comment: @Purushottamzende  hmmmmmmmmmm ok

Answer (score 0):

```
I'M changed the statement this :    

$statement = "`tbl_member` where member_id!=$member_id  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())>='$post[6]' AND 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())<='$post[7]' AND gender Like '$post[0]%' AND star LIKE '%$post[1]%' AND caste LIKE '%$post[2]%' AND  mari_status LIKE '%$post[3]%' AND education LIKE '%$post[5]%' AND city_town LIKE '$post[8]%' AND month_income LIKE '%$post[4]%' AND country_liv LIKE '%$post[9]%'";
```

to this :

```
$statement = "`tbl_member` where month_income LIKE '%$post[4]%' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())>='$post[6]' AND 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE())<='$post[7]' AND  member_id!=$member_id AND country_liv LIKE '%$post[9]%' AND gender Like '$post[0]%' AND star LIKE '%$post[1]%' AND caste LIKE '%$post[2]%' AND  mari_status LIKE '%$post[3]%' AND education LIKE '%$post[5]%' AND city_town LIKE '$post[8]%' ";
```

Thank you friends...its working for me